# Calculate the histogram of pixel values

Tags: gpu, openmp

This is my code for the stage1 part of calculating the histogram and returning the most common pixel value for the image. How can I improve it because this parallelization is not giving me better performance?

```
    #pragma omp parallel for private(t_y, p_x, p_y, tile_index, tile_offset, pixel_offset, pixel) schedule(dynamic, 1)
    for (t_x = 0; t_x < openMP_TILES_X; ++t_x) {
        for (t_y = 0; t_y < openMP_TILES_Y; ++t_y) {
            const unsigned int tile_index = (t_y * openMP_TILES_X + t_x);
            const unsigned int tile_offset = (t_y * openMP_TILES_X * TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE + t_x * TILE_SIZE);
            // For each pixel within the tile
            for (int p_x = 0; p_x < TILE_SIZE; ++p_x) {
                for (int p_y = 0; p_y < TILE_SIZE; ++p_y) {
                    // Load pixel
                    const unsigned int pixel_offset = (p_y * openMP_input_image.width + p_x);
                    const unsigned char pixel = openMP_input_image.data[tile_offset + pixel_offset];
                    openMP_histograms[tile_index].histogram[pixel]++;
                    global_histogram[pixel]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Find the most common contrast value
    unsigned long long max_c = 0;  // Max count of pixels with a specific contrast value
    int max_i = -1; // Index (contrast value) of the histogram bin with max_c, init with an invalid value
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) schedule(dynamic)
    for (i = 0; i < PIXEL_RANGE; ++i) {
        if (max_c < global_histogram[i]) {
            max_c = global_histogram[i];
            max_i = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the runtimes of your code compiled without openmp, compiled with openmp and running on 1, 2, 4, 8 threads... Besides: you don't need to flag variables as `private` when you declare them inside the parallel region (they are private by design); you have a race condition when updating the shared array `global_histogram[]`. You need `#pragma atomic` before this instruction.

Comment: You'd better calculate `global_histogram[]` after the parallel region by summing the histograms of each tile. And remove the `schedule(dynamic,1)` clause, unless you have a good reason to use it.

Comment: There is also a race condition when using `max_c`.  If you provide a [mre], we will try to make it faster.  @PierU it is better to use reduction (if possible).

Comment: Why is this tagged `gpu`?

Comment: #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (i = 0; i < PIXEL_RANGE; ++i) {
        if (max_c < global_histogram[i]) {
            max_c = global_histogram[i];
            max_i = i;
        }     Where to use the reduction here?

Comment: And also when I run this program in release mode Pixels test getting failed, all the pixels are not passing

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:max_c)`. But there's also a race confition on `max_i`: this one can be solved with an `atomic`pragma, but frankly you really don't need parallelizing this loop that iterates only 256 times. Still, there is a race condition on `global_histogram[]`, which can give wrong results.

Comment: @PierU: 1) You can use reduction on `global_histogram` -- `reduction(+:global_histogram[:PIXEL_RANGE]`, 2) if you put `max_c` and `max_i` in a struct you can create a used defined reduction (so it can be solved by using reduction only), but I agree that a serial code will be faster.

Comment: I tried it but the image pixels are not passing , but the Validation Status:
        Image width: Pass
        Image height: Pass
        Image pixels: Fail (61634/65536 wrong)
        Most common contrast value: Fail             Here, I am failing to pass all the pixels, furthermore in stage2 and stage3, I have to equalise the histogram and store the most common pixel value in the output global image.

Comment: Please declare all loop variables in the loop header. I think you have a problem with `t_y`.

Comment: You tried... what, precisely? And what do you mean by "pixels are not passing"? If you don't post the corrected code that you are using after our suggestions, then it's very hard to comment and help you.